# Include an IK Constraint Influence value in a Rigify Pose

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify, pose-mode

I want to include aspects that are normally reserved for animation into a character Pose, not into an animation.

In this case I had manually added bones to an armature (parent is Torso) and an IK constraint from an FK to an IK bone, and set the IK Influence to 1.

[image] -  [image]

Now I'd like to do the same with this for a Pose that I do with the Rigify tools, to change the IK Influence and then include this into a named Pose:

[image]   -  [image]

Note that my bones are properly to the FK and IK bone groups, but there is no FK->IK control for the Torso group.

An example use case might be like an elephant's trunk, that either swings loosely as a Softbody, or is influenced by a bone structure that controls it's use.

Is this possible to either:

1. through somehow converting my IK Constraint into a Rigify?
2. Adding some other bone Modifier or Constraint to allow this to be
   part of a pose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Just add the property to the generated rig

If you add bones to the generated rig in edit mode, you can select those bones in Pose mode and add Custom Properties that show up in the Rigify control panel.

Here's an example:

- I added `my bone` to a generated rig.
- In Pose mode, I added a custom property `my property to` my bone`
- When `my bone` is selected in pose mode, `my property` shows up under *properties* in the Rigify part of the side panel:

[image: rigify side panel showing additional custom property]

Of course, you have to be careful about letting rigify regenerate the rig

2. Adding a Rigify meta rig

Take a look at [Creating Meta-Rigs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/metarigs.html) in the manual for how to add a custom meta rig to a a metarig armature using one of the existing classes.  I know that there are already metarigs for trunks and tails.

Comment: Ah I see how to add the custom property, in my case I'll name it "IK>FK", and I see I can then Copy as New Driver and Paste Driver into my IK Modifier influence.  For some reason I can only set it like and int to either 0 or 1, but no slider setting and entering 0.5 is not allowed for some reason (and if I check Use Soft Limits, it is ignored and reset the next time I click on Edit!)

Comment: Can you better explain "you have to be careful about letting rigify regenerate the rig".  Does that mean I WANT to regenerate the rig ASAP?  Or the I should avoid doing so?

Comment: It means you should avoid doing so.  There are hoops you can go through to preserve your modifications but I always manage to screw those up.

Comment: When you set up the custom property, if you set the limits using integer values, then it will only take integer values in the input.  So you have to use 0.0 and 1.0 if you want to specify the range. Is that your problem?